# use dot product to show that the cross product between two vectors u and v is orthogonal

Tags: multivariable-calculus, cross-product

can you please check my work

Question: let u =  and v = , where the six components can be any real number. show,using the dot product, that the cross product uxv is perpendicular to both u =  and v =

attempt :

uxv  =  (u2v3 - u3v2, u3v1-v3u1, u1v2-v1u2>) and u.v = x1x2 + y1y2 + z1z2
i dont

Comment: How do you know when two vectors are orthogonal in general?

Comment: u and v are orthogonal if u.v = 0 i.e, x1x2+y1y2+z1z2 = 0.

Comment: OK.  Then just calculate $u\cdot (u\times v)$ and $v\cdot (u\times v)$ using the definitions and see if you get $0$.

Comment: u x v = (u2v3 - u3v2, u3v1 - u1v3, u1v2 - u2v1). how is this related to dot product. thanks

Comment: That's the vector that you need to dot with $u$ and $v$.

Comment: i see, thanks. it works

Comment: No problem. :-)